# How to get player_id in Ionic OneSignal?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, onesignal

I have a use case that I only have to send a `notification` to a specific user when I updated the user data from a desktop application. So that's why I need to get `player_id` generated by `OneSignal`? But their [documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/onesignal/) does not show everything.

Comment: instead of OneSignal, I recommend to use FCM

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `addsubscriptionobserver` Ref: [addSubscriptionObserver](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/cordova-sdk#section--addsubscriptionobserver-)

```
this.oneSignal.addSubscriptionObserver().subscribe((state) => {
   if (!state.from.subscribed && state.to.subscribed) {
    console.log("Subscribed for OneSignal push notifications! :: ID "+state.to.userId);
   }
});
```